# Why not simply use class in html/css all the time instead of id?

Tags: html, css

I read that `id` can only be used once in a html document while `class` can be used multiple number of times. If this is the case, why don't programmers simply use `class` all the time? Wouldn't this make things simpler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A few reasons:

**1:** Id's are for targeting one element, while classes are for multiple
Example:

```
<div id="test">This is red</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>

#test{
background:red;
}
```

**2:** Id's overrule classes in CSS
Example:

```
<div class="test" id="test">Test</div>
#test{ 
background:red;//Overrides, even though it is higher in the document
}
.test{
background:blue;
}
```

**3:** Id's are used for anchor links in HTML
Example:

```
<a href="#test">Link to test</a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

**4:** Id's are easier to select with JavaScript

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
document.getElementById("test"); //returns the element
document.getElementsByClassName("test"); //returns a HTMLCollection, which is like an array
```

Comment: Possibly typo in number 3 (`href="#test"`)

Comment: @mr5 thanks for pointing that out! will edit :D

Answer (score 1):

I remember one of the things is that IDs have higher specificity than classes. There may be times when a declaration conflicts with another declaration. These conflicts are resolved using the Cascade rules. In simple terms, if a class selector and ID selector were to be in conflict, the ID selector would be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want **exactly one element** and not all elements with the same class. The class is to design a **group of elements**. The id is used to identify and modify a single element.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to target a specific, unique, element not just an entire class of elements. the `ID` attribute allows you to target unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

ID can also be REFERENCED as many times as you want but the ID itself needs to be unique, the same way the class name does.

You can target a specific element with an ID but using a class you target everything with that class associated to it.

There is no limit to the number of times you can reference either an ID or a class within the HTML or CSS itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few reasons:

- higher specificity
- you can use ids in links like http://mypage#section
- you can combine ids with classes, eg `id="comment_id_700" class="comment"`

...but there's a general rule: "if you don't need them don't use them"